# TypeScript doesn't think my dynamic object key lookup is ever undefined (when it could be)

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript codebase (v4.7.3) with `"strict": true` enabled is my `tsconfig`, and I have code like the following (basically, a hashmap where some keys may exist and others not):

```
// Cache promises in a hashmap, where the key is some unique identifier, and
// the value is a Promise object
const promiseCache: { [key: string]: Promise<void> } = {};

// I expect TypeScript to flag the below expression as possibly being undefined
// and require me to wrap the below line in an `if` statement to ensure the
// promise at the specified key actually exists
promiseCache['4c8e17ce-9ca5-457a-925e-a8c36fe90508'].then(() => {
    console.log('then!');
});
```

Obviously, the above code is simplified to demonstrate the problem, but the nature of what I'm doing is the same: a hashmap that starts out empty, and a square-bracket key lookup to look up the value dynamically.

I have gathered that `{ [key: string]: ... }` is the generally-correct way to define objects with dynamic keys. However, I expect this construct to abide by the other rules of TypeScript - namely, that

I have searched Google and StackOverflow the best I can, and have not been able to find any issues that are remotely similar. My issue is trying to understand why TypeScript is *not* showing an "... is possibly undefined" type of error.

What can I do to enforce the strict null/undefined checking for my code above?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess